# Jquery/Javascript Regular expression to filter decimal numbers with comma, 13 int places and 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi I need help with an input. I need to make a regular expression that filter it on keypress.

The input will have a number with max 13 int places and max 2 decimal places. In addition the decimal number uses a comma instead of dot.

I tried some regex but they don't works on keypress.

```
111111,11 TRUE
1111111111111 TRUE 
11111111111111 FALSE
11111111111111,11 FALSE
1111111111111,11 TRUE
111,111 FALSE
1a FALSE
1.0 FALSE
1.00 FALSE
0 TRUE
```

I tried the following regular expression, and tested it on regextester website.
In that site it partially works (some cases still not working), but on javascript it doesn't filter. I don't know the reason.

```
/^(\d{1,13})(\,)?(\d{1,2})$/g
```

This is the jquery method

```
$(".numericWithDecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
    var regex = /^(\d{1,13})(\,)?(\d{1,2})$/g;

   //I tried this
   if(!regex.match($(this).val()))
     event.preventDefault();

   //or this
   if (!regex.test($(this).val()))
     event.preventDefault();

});
```

Is possible to create an expression that works with these cases? What is?

[EDIT] New method based on @The fourth bird regex

```
 $(".numericWithDecimalLimit").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
         var regex = /^(?:\d{1,13})(?:,\d{1,2})?$/g;
         var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.charCode);     
         if(!regex.test(value))
             event.preventDefault();    
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your regex to and include the comma into a non capturing group and make it optional:

[`^(\d{1,13})(?:,\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/cUMlyP/1)

That would match:

- `^` Beginning of the string
- `(\d{1,13})` Capture 1 - 13 digits in a group
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `,` Match a comma
  - `\d{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` End of the string

For the match you could also make the first group a non capturing group:

[`^(?:\d{1,13})(?:,\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/cUMlyP/2)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I tried your regex in the regex website tester and it works.

So I tried a method to filter the insert, but it doesn't works..
I edited my question with the new method. Where is the error?
Thanks

Comment: @AleCataalyst I think it should be `event.preventDefault();`. You could log the `var value` and see if it contains a comma. But every time this code runs on one of these events `keypress keyup blur`, you evaluate your `var value`. But when you enter a comma, the string to evaluate is for example `123,`. That will not be matched by the regex

Comment: Yes, I fixed the method "preventDefault()"

Did you say that I should evaluate the only char and not the entire string? 
I think that I need to check the entire string (123,) because in this way I can check if the length is > 13 or 2 decimal places. Right?

So, I don't understand where is the problem on my method

Comment: This line `var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.charCode);` will be executed for all the events. If you log the `var value` and you enter for example 3 in an input field, you log will show you 3 and then 33. Then if you lose focus, it will be triggered again. Let say you use only `keypress blur`, enter `12,` and log your value. You would only see 12 in  your textbox and in your log you would see `12,`. Now on every keypress this line `if(!regex.test(value)) {` will be executed but as soon as you enter a comma this will never pass. So `12,1` will never be reached.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, but how can I pass the test with the comma? D:

Comment: You could [match the comma](https://regex101.com/r/HCn6N2/1) using only `keypress blur` but that would also allow for `12,`. You could also do the verification on the complete string when for example submitting.

Comment: thank you bro. This is probably the only solution...

Thank you again for the patient :)

Answer (score 0):

after making a small update in your original regex to include dots, seems to be working as expected for me.. I got this in the end `/^(\d{1,13})(,|\.)?(\d{1,2})$/g`

here are a few test cases:

```js
var regex = /^(\d{1,13})(,|\.)?(\d{1,2})$/g;

console.log(regex.test('111111.11'));

console.log(regex.test('1111111111111'));

console.log(regex.test('11111111111111'));

console.log(regex.test('11111111111111,11'));

console.log(regex.test('1111111111111,11'));

console.log(regex.test('111,111'));

console.log(regex.test('1a'));

console.log(regex.test('1.0'));

console.log(regex.test('1.00'));

console.log(regex.test('0'));
```

Comment: I need to use only comma and not dot..
However the expression doesn't works for the 0 value.